# What can we say about convergence of $ \frac{\sum_{s=1}^k a_s^2b_s}{\sum_{s=1}^k a_s} $ when $\sum a_n=\infty$ and $(b_n)\geq 0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

My original question is [Assumption on Mirror Descent convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226420/assumption-on-mirror-descent-connvergence)
 but I realized that it boils down into the following question:

Suppose $\sum a_n =\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ where $(a_n)$ is positive and $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Also, $(b_n)$ is non-negative and bounded.

What can we say about convergence of $ \frac{\sum_{s=1}^k a_s^2b_s}{\sum_{s=1}^k a_s} $?

Comment: Is $(a_n)$ a non convergent sequence or is $\sum a_n$ is a divergent series?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: $\sum{a_n}=\infty$

Comment: You have clearly said $(a_n)$ is a 'divergent sequence'. Please try to distinguish between sequences and series.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: My fault. I will edit the statement.

Comment: There is another hypothesis in your link that says $a_n \to 0$. Please be careful in posting your question. Any 'little' hypothsis can make a big difference.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: You are right. I will be.

Comment: you are missing the hypothesis that $b_n$ is bounded.. This question was completely answered in your first thread.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226420/assumption-on-mirror-descent-convergence